Sharing Database tables data across 2 micro-services
We have couple of microservices, first microservice A has some data which is like reference data, we plan to share these data with other microservices, plan is to have copies of the data in micoservice A in all microservices that might want to refer to it. Looking for the best possible design and architecture for this usecase.
We have tried to copy the data of Microservice A, to say microservice B and C, which needs to refer to the reference data i.e A's data, and created an events for CRUD operations to propogate the changes from microservices A to B and C, so that they could update the changes on to the copy of the data that they have. My concern is this may not be the right approach as we have created the copies of A instead of keeping single source of truth, we now have the challenge of syncing the data to keep then relevant and then might need reconciliation to ensure that the data copies don't go out of sync.
I am looking for alternative solutions if any and respective trade-offs.

Querying the data
If microservice B wants to check that a data exists in microservice A, it can just make a HEAD request to microservice A. A HEAD request is fine to just check to existence of a data, it just returns a status code without the body, that's faster. That's my default choice of implementation, because it is simple and fast. You can add a bit of cache if the same data are checked repeatedly.
Replicating the data
Microservice A logs every change (creation, modification and deletion) into a message log like Kafka or Rabbit Stream. Other services consume the messages to remain up-to-date. The at-least-one policy ensures that no messages are missed, so the microservices do not go out-of-sync. You also want to monitor the lag, to be sure the microservices consume the messages as fast as they are produced. That's what I do if lot of checks have to be done, in order to speed up things.
